# Is it possible to find this integral exactly?

Tags: integration

$$\int_{l}^{M}(j-1)^{\beta -2}\sqrt{j}  \text{ d}j \quad \beta \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have not tried anything useful. I have tried various substitutions and have come to a dead end each time.

Comment: Please show us what particular substitution you tried ?

Comment: No, this is an incomplete Beta integral, it has no closed form. (And when the bounds are $l=0,M=1$, you will need the Gamma function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Yves Daoust, we must use the [incomplete beta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17)

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}_{x}(a,b) = \int\limits_{0}^{x} z^{a-1}(1-z)^{b-1} dz
\end{equation}

If we split the integral, we have
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{l}^{M} (j-1)^{\beta - 2} j^{1/2} dj &= (-1)^{\beta - 2} \int\limits_{l}^{M} (1-j)^{\beta - 2} j^{1/2} dj \\
&= (-1)^{\beta - 2} \left( \int\limits_{0}^{M} (1-j)^{\beta - 2} j^{1/2} dj - 
\int\limits_{0}^{l} (1-j)^{\beta - 2} j^{1/2} dj \right) \\
&= (-1)^{\beta - 2} \big[ \mathrm{B}_{M}(3/2,\beta - 1) - \mathrm{B}_{l}(3/2,\beta - 1) \big]
\end{align}